# github remove newline from the env

Tags: github, github-actions

I have below workflow with workflow dispatcher

```
jobs:
  deploy_infra:
    name: Deploy Infra    
    env:
      INFRA_ACCOUNT: >
        ${{ fromJson('{
              "dev": "12345",
              "preprd": "678234",
              "prd": "91056"
            }')[github.event.inputs.stage] }}
    steps:
      - name: Creating ARN
     
        shell: bash
        run: |
         echo "ARN is arn:aws:iam::${{ env.INFRA_ACCOUNT }}:role/aws-github-role"
```

Now this give me output as for stage as `"dev"`

```
ARN is arn:aws:iam::12345
:role/aws-github-role
```

How to fix the line break after the account number?

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the environment variable as follows:

```yaml
      INFRA_ACCOUNT: >
        ${{ fromJson('{
              "dev": "12345",
              "preprd": "678234",
              "prd": "91056"
            }')[github.event.inputs.stage] }}
```

With the `>` operator, it adds a line break at the end.
However, this can be configured using the [Block Chomping Indicator](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#8112-block-chomping-indicator).

The default behavior ("Clipping") preserves the last line break without any trailing empty lines.
You can change this to `Stripping` by using `>-` instead of `>`. This results in the final line break being removed:

```yaml
      INFRA_ACCOUNT: >-
        ${{ fromJson('{
              "dev": "12345",
              "preprd": "678234",
              "prd": "91056"
            }')[github.event.inputs.stage] }}
```